# В зависимости от ip пользователя показывать ему нужный файл, но по одному и тому же адресу

Tags: php, redirect, редирект

На данный момент реализовано редиректом - в зависимости от страны пользователя редиректит на определенный `url`.

Проблема в том, что нужно в зависимости от страны пользователю показывать разные страницы, но на одном и том же `url`.

К примеру,

- пользователь России переходит на `test.ru/index.php` видит форум
- пользователь США на `test.ru/index.php` видит блог админа

---

есть база, на индексе есть код:

```
<?php
require_once('geo.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
if ($geoplugin->countryCode == "RU") {
    $redirect_url = "http://test.ru/1.php";
} else {
    $redirect_url = "http://test.ru/2.php";
}
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Location:' . $redirect_url);
```

На geo.php определяется ip и по нему страна через онлайн-базу.
Как раз таки не понятно как вместо редиректа вставлять нужную страницу на индексе.

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо за ответы

Comment: если полученный ответ был вам полезен, вы можете его отметить как верный — галочка слева от ответа. Это местный способ сказать «спасибо».

Comment: А ещё, публикуйте новые ответы, только если хотите действительно дать ответ на вопрос. Вы можете оставлять комментарии под своим вопросом а также редактировать его кнопкой [edit].

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать через php. Вам нужна база стран по IP, например, `SxGeo`. После подключения встраиваете в главную что-то вроде:

```
<?php
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  if($SxGeo->get($ip) == 'US') {
     //тут отображение блога. Можете как-нибудь с помощью include сделать.
  } elseif($SxGeo->get($ip) == 'RU') {
     //тут форум
  }
?>
```

Это самый простой пример. Вы можете использовать другую базу или даже сделать свою. Так же, если вы параноик и боитесь, что кто-то через прокси/VPN проберётся на ваш форум, то тоже нужно будет искать пути защиты.

Comment: @Альфия самое простое и глупое - сделать iFrame, который будет растянут на всю страницу.

Comment: в порядке паранойи - желательна реализация, при которой пользователь не сможет без прокси/впн увидеть не предназначенное ему, думаю через iframe это вряд ли возможно.

Comment: @Альфия Через iframe вы сможете адекватно и без проблем отображать нужный файл. Вам просто нужно найти готовый код (уже есть в интернетах), который определяет реальный IP и вставить проверку не только на главную, но и на каждую страницу блога/форума.

Comment: можно и сделать это через htaccess?
к примеру: 


        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !93.143.174.0 
        RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.html [L,QSA] 

при этом нужно заменить конкретный ip на определение страны? или в одном файле определять страну, а в данную конструкцию прописывать?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно всё решение упирается в остальную часть кода. Самый простой вариант:

```
if ($geoplugin->countryCode == "RU") {
    include("1.php");
} else {
    include("2.php");
}
```

Если весь остальной код будет работать без проблем, то на этом можно остановиться.
Только предупреждение - поисковики за такой трюк могут забанить:
[Фрагмент](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/seo/search/ban-yandeks-popast-pod-ags-filtr-pereoptimizaciyu-kontenta-vyxod.html) с первого попавшегося сайта в поиске:
**За что можно получить бан в Яндексе?**
Клоакинг — это когда поисковым роботам (их узнают по юзернейму, которым они представляются при заходе на сайт или Ip адресу) выдает один контент (как правило, переоптимизированный и трудночитаемый), а посетителям совершенно другой (без лишних ключей и вполне себе лаконичный). Клоакинг активно использовался на заре становления поисковых систем, когда те еще не наказывали за спам ключами и т.п. вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Определять IP можно через онлайн сервис, например:

```
$geo = file_get_contents('http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/89.163.220.14');
$geo = json_decode($geo);
var_dump($geo);
```

Или через GeoIP (http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php) - это предпочтительный вариант.

Подробнее об обоих способах можно почитать тут: http://atoumus.github.io/PHP/php-detect-country-by-ip.html